# PHP: echo only the last part of a url, intead code printing the whole url

Tags: php

I wanted to print the last characters after "/" in a url. but instead it is printing the whole url,  I expected the output to be just "index.php" instead it is printing out the whole url.

How should i go about doing it right?

```
 $data = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $whatIWant = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1); 
     echo $whatIWant;
```

You can see it [here](http://spiritofethiopia.com/test/test/test/index.php)

Comment: All this use of explode to hack through to the filename when PHP provides built-in functions to do it for you: `echo pathinfo(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_BASENAME);`

Comment: What is the difference to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29552114/3933332 ? Seems pretty similar?

Comment: strrpos is much better.

Comment: Please try strrpos.it's best solution.see the code i have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php
$data = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$whatIWant = explode("/",$data);
 echo end($whatIWant);?>
```

Comment: @Jocker *it is help ful means accept my answer* NO! This doesn't mean that OP has to accept exactly your answer. Maybe an upV because that's what the tooltip says: *This answer is useful*; There is a good post on meta how accepting works and which may helps OP to decide which answer he can/should choose/accept: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234

Answer (score 1):

You should get the actual link by

```
<?php
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$getpath=explode("/",$actual_link);
echo end($getpath);
?>
```

**Short Explanation :**

**Step 1 :** Get the url by

```
http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

**Step 2 :** Explode with slash

```
explode("/",$actual_link)
```

**Step 3 :** Get the last part

```
end($getpath);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, with a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it this way using  `strrchr` :

```
$url = 'http://spiritofethiopia.com/test/test/test/index.php';
$str = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
echo $str;
```

> `strrchr` — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string.

Comment: This works, but i don't want to place the url manually to all my pages

Comment: you can also use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of manual url. I just used manual url  for providing you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

working solution,

```
<?php 

  $url = 'http://test/test/test/index.php';
  $tokens = explode('/', $url);
  echo $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-1];

?>
```

Comment: if string contain more slashes.your code did'nt work at all.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I have corrected the answer

Comment: @JenisPatel: It's working fine, I have checked with your url as well.

Comment: I do not think so it works for you as you are using `substr($test,15)` you are giving a fixed position number `15` so for `$test = 'test/test/test/test/index.php';` the output will be `/test/index.php ` not `index.php`

Comment: @JenisPatel: I have changed my answer long back.

Comment: Okay fine :) Just check your updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74917/discussion-between-madhu-and-jenis-patel).

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match whith a correct RegExp  to capture the end of the URL.

```
<?php
$data = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(preg_match('#/([^/]*?)$#', $data, $matches) == 1) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
else {
    // Should not happen
    /*
     * Throw exception
     */
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try strripos instead of strpos, it may works

```
<?php
    $data = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $whatIWant = substr($data, strripos($data, "/") + 1); 
        echo $whatIWant;
    ?>
```